# Cannot change intent filter in android manifest

Tags: android

I have 3 activities in this android studio project. I'm tasked with starting them each separately by moving the intent filter into the activity, however I'm unable to start one of my activities. The same activity doesn't have a /activity> closing tag and I'm not sure why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sean.lab1">

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".ListItemsActivity"></activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

I am able to  move the intent tag to my ListItemsActivity and it will start, but I am not able to move the intent filter tag to my LoginActivity, nor does LoginActivity have a closing `</activity>` tag.

Comment: the LogInActivity has a closing tag. You can short up the tags by just using `/>` , so it´s closed too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListItemsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ListItemsActivity"></activity>
 </application>
```